# shininess, emissive and specular are not a property of this material in React VR

Tags: blender, wavefront, webvr, react-360

I'm developing an application with React VR and I've created an 3D pokeball with blender. I've export this as Wavefront `.obj` file and use it in my React VR application.

In the console I see this warnings:

> **`THREE.MeshBasicMaterial`**: `shininess`, `emissive` and `specular` are not a property of this material.

Below you could find my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, asset, StyleSheet, Pano, Text, View, Mesh } from 'react-vr';

class pokemongo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Pano source={asset('sky.jpg')} />
        <Mesh source={{ mesh: asset('pokeball.obj'), mtl: asset('pokeball.mtl') }} 
              style={{ height: 1 }} 
              transform={{ rotate: '0 90 0' }}></Mesh>
      </View>
    );
  }
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('pokemongo', () => pokemongo);
```

This is the rendered output

[image]

And on [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/HeinPauwelyn/32076ebfcd4dbd656b133d0cb87a782c) you could find the `obj` and `mtl` file and could you download the `blend` file.

Here you could see my pokeball in Blender.

[image]

I've searched on the internet but didn't found solutions or documentation about the problem related with React VR.

What I've done wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shouldn't be a problem anymore in `react-vr > 0.2.1` like the [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/issues/92) states.

Furthermore, if you want your models to be rendered with colors and shading you'll need to apply some lights to the scene. This is done by enabling the `lit` prop on the model and using either `AmbientLight`, `SpotLight` or `DirectionalLight` components in your scene.

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  AppRegistry,
  asset,
  Pano,
  View,
  Model,
  AmbientLight,
  SpotLight
} from "react-vr";

class pokemongo extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Pano source={asset("chess-world.jpg")} />
        <AmbientLight intensity={0.5} />
        <SpotLight
          intensity={1}
          style={{ transform: [{ translate: [-5, 5, 0] }] }}
        />
        <Model
          source={{
            obj: asset("pokeball.obj"),
            mtl: asset("pokeball.mtl")
          }}
          style={{
            layoutOrigin: [0.5, 0.5],
            transform: [
              { translate: [0, 0, -10] }
            ]
          }}
          lit={true}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent("pokemongo", () => pokemongo);
```

[image: 3d model in vr]

For the spinning animation you can check out the [ModelSample](https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/blob/master/Examples/ModelSample/index.vr.js) to see how it's made.